# Three.js first person controls with commands on screen

Tags: three.js, 3d, controls

I'm using three.js to visualize some 3D objects.

I need to use a first person control also with the mobile. How to do it? By using some commands on screen? Is there such a library that could help me?

I am actually using `FirstPersonControls.js` and works on desktop.
I also tried `PointerLockControls.js`, still works exclusively on desktop.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [TouchControls](https://github.com/mese79/TouchControls)? There is also a [live example](http://touchcontrols.kissr.com/) that demonstrates the FPS-controls for touch devices.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!